# bootstrap stacking middle column

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I just started using bootstrap.. i am trying to create a page with three column.

The middle column then needs to split into further ten rows. Each row will then have corresponding php echos

I have added the code on what i am doing on this page

http://www.bootply.com/BYbAeQUSsB#

I need to know if this is the right way of  making rows in a column or is there another efficient way. i need to be responsive.

Comment: The Bootstrap markup looks fine. What specific problem/question do you have?

Comment: when i minimise  it on chrome to see how the responsive looks.the ..the purple stays next to blue.While the other stack up under blue column. on iphone it looks okay.Firefox it looks okay. when i look at mobile view on-line it looks okay..So don't know it is chrome misbehaving or my markup is wrong

Comment: That doesn't happen for me. All the columns stack with blue on top.

Comment: thanks .Must be my chrome